# Return true if view consist multiple table else false

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need return result in terms of true or false from Stored Procedure by detecting a view contains multiple tables or not.

## Attempt:

```
CREATE PROC spTest
@ViewName nvarchar(max)

AS

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(max)


SET @SQL = 'SELECT  @TableName = Table_Name  
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
                 WHERE View_Name = ''' + @ViewName  + ''''
                 
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@TableName nvarchar(max) OUTPUT', @TableName output

IF (@TableName > 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'True'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'False'
END
GO
```

**Note**: I am not getting how to insert all `tables` from `view` into `@TableName` variable and check the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROC Sptest @ViewName NVARCHAR(max)
AS
DECLARE @cnt INT

SELECT @cnt = Count(*)
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE  VIEW_NAME = @ViewName

IF ( @cnt > 1 )
  BEGIN
      SELECT 'True'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
      SELECT 'False'
  END
```

Answer (score 2):

you can achive your goal through this

```
create PROC spTest
@ViewName nvarchar(max)

AS

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)


SET @SQL = '
DECLARE @TableName table (table_name varchar(1000))
insert into @TableName 
SELECT   Table_Name  
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
                 WHERE View_Name = ''' + @ViewName  + '''


IF (select count(1) from  @TableName )> 1
BEGIN
    SELECT ''True''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT ''False''
END'
exec (@SQL)
GO
```

After creating procedure execute procedure 
spTest 'pace_entity_access_view'

Comment: Have you tested this query ?? Is it really working ??

Comment: I didn't execute previous query but i have did some changes please do this go ahead.